# Converting matlab program to equivalent python code

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In want to implement the below listed Matlab commands in Python. I am able to figure out the Matlab equivalent commands in Python, but i am not getting the exact result. Can someone please help me to achieve so.

MATLAB CODE:

```
n0 = 3
n1 = 1
n2 = 5
n = [n1:n2]
>> 1 2 3 4 5
x = [(n - n0) == 0]
>> 0 0 1 0 0
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
import numpy 
n0 = 3
n1 = 1
n2 = 5
n = r_[n1:n2+1]
>> [1 2 3 4 5]
x = r_[(n-n0) == 0]
>> [False False True False False]
```

So x is my array with boolean data type " [array([False, False,  True, False False], dtype=bool)]". How can i make my last command to return result in form of 0's or 1's such that result is exactly same as Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a list comprehension to convert bool to int:

```
[int(val) for val in x]
```

Comment: Thx, it can be used with array command such that the returned list is of ndarray data type. But is there a way that while i was executing the command, result will directly be in that type. I know there are some methods/attributes in numpy array by which data types can be controlled.